# Comparing many event studies

Tags: time-series, interaction, data-transformation, linear

I am studying the impact of an event on around 100 timeseries $i$ with weekly observations $t$.

$y_{i,t} = \beta_{1}\text{post-event} + \beta_{2} \text{week number} + \beta_{3} \text{(post-event X week number)} $

where the week number is set to 0 the week before the event.

My goal is to understand which timeseries are more or less impacted by the event especially in terms of the trend ($\beta_{3}$).

There is relatively high variance in the values observed between timeseries, but not so much within any timeseries. Some vary between 5-6 thousand, some vary between 200-300.

I have received conflicting advice about transforming the dependent variable to facilitate comparison:

- either taking a logarithm, so that the coefficient $\beta_{3}$ can be interpreted as a percent change;
- or standardizing by the pre-event data within each time series (minus the mean, dividing by the standard deviation), leading to an interpretation in terms of standard deviations.

Trying both I am surprised to find that these transformations result in a quite different ranking of which timeseries are most affected. I would like to understand this better and appreciate any advice.